# Copy a const CComPtr

Tags: c++, atl

I created a new class. This class needs a pointer to an interface.
I get this pointer by another class.

My member:
CComPtr memberPointerABC;

But I got the pointer by the other class as CONST.
const CComPtr& GetABCPointer();

How can I set the provided const Pointer to my member pointer?

A normal assignment does not work:
memberPointerABC=GetABCPointer()

Comment: Did you try const_cast (http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)?

Comment: This works for me. One thing I note is that you don't have the template parameter when using `CComPtr`. How exactly is `CComPtr` parameterized in either of the cases?

Comment: Could you provide more code, what you want to achieve and what compiler errors you are getting on the way?